# Button has no ID and no Name, python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a little software with python and I have to get to YouTube with Requests-Python, but everytime I have to accept the Cookie-License. So I started with Selenium, but i cant find the button ID and the name or the value,...

The Source Code:

```
<button class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc IIdkle" jscontroller="soHxf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc; touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsname="higCR" aria-label=""><div class="VfPpkd-Jh9lGc"></div><span jsname="V67aGc" class="VfPpkd-vQzf8d" aria-hidden="true"></span><div class="VfPpkd-RLmnJb"></div></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium has many options additionally to id.
For example, try to use css locator

```
locator = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".VfPpkd-LgbsSe.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf.nCP5yc.AjY5Oe.DuMIQc.IIdkle")
```

Remove classes that do not make this locator unique to make the locator shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with your help!